Need help to identify SMD component, "BDXCLC", SO-8
I can't find anything  that is matching with a 8 pin smd  chip marked BDXCLC. The board is the electric motor controller of "ninebot Es2" scooter. As far as I can understand, it should be part of buck converter step down or dc to dc converter with 12 Volts output (input 30 - 45 volts. Pls. check the attached photo, component circled in red.

I'm looking for a datasheet and a possible replacement.

Gonna be a pain in the neck to replace that one. Cooling pad and that blob of silicone/hot glue(?) next to it. The board looks quite polluted in general - the connectors are covered in goo too, which is one big no-no. It might eat itself in between the socket and the crimp.

Thankyou. Yes indeed. I had to remove all the silicon above....

Remove the silicone not the silicon :) Very easy to mix those two up for us who aren't native English speakers.

It's a Silergy SY8502FCC step-down converter.


(Source: lcsc.com)

I think you've found the right part. But to make things complicated, there's an obscure Japanese manufacturer Bellnix which also has a BDX family of step-down converters, but not in SO8 package.
